# How to limit the kafka print rate when using log4j2 to appender log to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, log4j2

I use log4j-kafka-appender to send flink-job's log to kafka topic. I successed to do it, but i don't know how to limit the send-rate for kafka appender.
for example： I want to send record <= 3record/s no matter how big the QPS is
thanks very much!

Comment: You could try increasing the kafka producer's batch size, but that isn't going to prevent the total amount of logs that the log4j appender sees. Only way to adjust that would be to set the log level of certain packages

Comment: thanks for your answer, We just need to collect the error log，we are worried that the jitter of the platform will lead to a sudden increase in error logs，Cause Kafka downtime

Comment: I've worked in environments where Kafka gets millions of messages per second, so I don't think that would be an issue